# Bucket names must start and end with a number or letter

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload a `.sav` file to firebase storage. But everytime I try uploaded I get this error: `ValueError: Bucket names must start and end with a number or letter.` None of the tutorials / questions that I've found online work to solve this.

The way I'm doing this is:

```py
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = 'credentials.json'
storer = storage.Client()
bucket = storer.get_bucket('gs://project_name.appspot.com/') #I found this on the top of my storage account.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

get_bucket takes the name of the bucket without "gs://" and without the trailing slash (which is not a number or letter, as the error message is reminding you).

```
bucket = storer.get_bucket('project_name.appspot.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

the **gs** in storage bucket should not be there it should be like this -

```
bucket = storer.get_bucket('project_name.appspot.com/') #I found this on the top of my storage account.
```

Comment: 1) How is your answer better than Doug's answer? 2) Your answer is actually wrong. The bucket name does not have the trailing slash `/` character. `Bucket names can only contain lowercase letters, numeric characters, dashes (-), underscores (_), and dots (.).`